# Underscore.js - Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I keep getting this Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined error when my script is trying to render a template. This script is using combinations of backbone.js, require.js, underscore.js, and jquery.js. I have spent a day trying to debug and search for answers online. Does anybody know what is going on?

Code:

```
define([
    'jQuery',
    'Underscore',
    'Backbone',
    'text!templates/sharingFactory.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, SharingFactoryTemplate) {
    console.log('in SharingFactoryItemView');
    var SharingFactoryItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "span",
        initialize: function() {
            console.log('in initialize');
            this.template = _.template(SharingFactoryTemplate);
            console.log(this);
            this.render();
        },
        render: function () {
            console.log('in render');
            var data = this.model.toJSON();
            console.log(data);
            this.$el.html(this.template(data));
            return this;
        }
    });

    return SharingFactoryItemView; 
});
```

Console Log:

```
in initialize SharingFactoryItemView.js:14
child
 SharingFactoryItemView.js:16
in render SharingFactoryItemView.js:20
Object
 SharingFactoryItemView.js:22
Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
```

Comment: You need to paste the code inside "templates/sharingFactory.html" and as the error said in the HTML there is some place where you are using a var x but it is not declared.

Comment: Attach please you model code and and the code you pass model to the view. Looks like the issue in your model